# plot multiple y values against one x values in python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, matplotlib

Here is my y values:

```
[1.00, 
[(1.99-2.27e-17j),(0.61+9.08e-17j), (0.12-0j)], 
[(1.9+4.54e-17j), (0.61-9.081e-17j), (0.12+4.54e-17j)], 
[(1.99+4.5e-17j), (0.61-9.08e-17j), (0.12+4.54e-17j)], 
[(1.99-2.27e-17j), (0.61+9.0e-17j), (0.12-0j)], 
3.00]
```

And here is my x values:

```
array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])
```

As you can see, the first and last x values correspond to one y value , the rest of the x values correspond to multiple y values. So how to plot the real part of y values against x  ?

Comment: Question with solution similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280444/python-scatter-plot-with-multiple-y-values-for-each-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that might help you. Note that this isn't really efficient (especially a problem for bigger datasets), but might put you on the right track. The main issue is that the dimensionality between your `xs` and `ys` is not the same.

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ys = [1.00, 
[(1.99-2.27e-17j),(0.61+9.08e-17j), (0.12-0j)], 
[(1.9+4.54e-17j), (0.61-9.081e-17j), (0.12+4.54e-17j)], 
[(1.99+4.5e-17j), (0.61-9.08e-17j), (0.12+4.54e-17j)], 
[(1.99-2.27e-17j), (0.61+9.0e-17j), (0.12-0j)], 
3.00]

xs = array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])

pxs = []
pys = []
for i, yelems in enumerate(ys):
    x = xs[i]
    try:
        for yelem in yelems:
            pxs.append(x)
            pys.append(yelem.real)
    except TypeError:
        pxs.append(x)
        pys.append(yelems)

plt.plot(pxs, pys)
plt.show()
```

As you can see I simply create two (one-dimensional) lists where I re-use the respective `x` value as needed so that `pxs` and `pys` have the same length. The `TypeError` is raised when trying to iterate over a float in the inner `for` loop, i.e. when `yelems` is only one element instead of a list.

I also assumed that you only want the `real` part of the `yelems` if there are multiple values (`yelems` is a list rather than a float) for one `x`.

### Update:

Regarding your question below whether the data can be "plotted directly", I have never used data like that with Matplotlib where the y dimensions vary across the x range.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might be able to clean up the code by being smart about the `ys` entries (i.e. make the ones at the end lists rather than floats for consistency) and/or use list comprehensions and/or tricks with `zip` for a more "compact" feel where you call `plot`.

If at all possible, personally I would try and get the input data straight as early on as possible to avoid the need for such re-arrangements of the entries.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have use the spirit of your method to rewrite my code and it works. But is it possible for python to directly plot x:[1,2,3]  y:[1, [1,2,3], 3]?

Comment: You're welcome. See my update regarding your question.